# How to create an Eclipse plugin proving libraries

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

I have an Eclipse plugin which needs to use methods from a certain library (say XYZ.jar). Up to know, I had the library in my lib-folder of the plugin. Since the underlying RCP-application changed, I get class loader problems and the people responsible for the RCP suggested that I should create a plugin, which only contains the problematic libraries and make them available to my plugin. How would such a plugin look like? I tried to create one, put the XYZ-jar inside but I don't know how to export packages for my plugin. In the "Runtime"-Tab I cannot add anything to the "Exported Packages"-part. The plugin-files look like this (sorry, I might have misconfigured them as I'm not so familiar with what goes where).

MANIFEST.MF

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: Libraries used by xxx
Bundle-SymbolicName: de.somthing.more;singleton:=true
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.qualifier
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.8
Bundle-ActivationPolicy: lazy
Bundle-ClassPath: lib/XYZ.jar
```

plugin.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?eclipse version="3.4"?>
<plugin>

</plugin>
```

build.properties

```
bin.includes = META-INF/,\
               plugin.xml,\
               lib/XYZ.jar
jars.compile.order = lib/XYZ.jar
source.lib/XYZ.jar =
```

Can anybody help to set up this plugin correctly?

Comment: Is the XYZ.jar still in the `lib` directory?

Comment: @greg-449: It's in the lib-directory of the new plugin now instead of the lib-directory where it has been before

Comment: This looks reasonable but this sort of thing is very difficult to diagnose remotely. One thing is that you probably don't want `;singleton:=true` on the Bundle-SymbolicName entry.